# Как с помощью синуса построить траекторию полёта птицы?

Tags: javascript, математика, анимация

График траектории должен принимать разную амплитуду.

Это схематический полёт птицы в игре. Птица летит слева направо, график её полёта просто похож на синус, но нужно как-то менять амплитуду и длину волны:

```
birds.y = Math.sin(birds.x)+200;
```

Если так, то она дёргается вверх и вниз на 1, соответственно =) 200 это отступ сверху.

```
birds.y = 4 * Math.sin(birds.x)+200;
```

Амплитуда увеличивается на 4, но длина остаётся под вопросом:

```
birds.y = 100*Math.sin(birds.x/100)+200;
```

Так получаю более ли менее полёт, но он однообразен.

Так, думаю, будет ещё понятней:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот, собственно, ещё для наглядности, под мониторы не подстраивал, но птицу видно =)

[На сайте](http://smartcook.info/test/)

Может, её к курсу валют прикрутить? =))

Comment: Ну, умножайте базовую высоту полета птицы на синус случайной величины. Вы же все равно не озвучиваете каким должен быть результат...

Comment: Птицы по синусу не летают

Comment: Нужно складывать много разных синусов.

Comment: Ваш пример #3 позволяет птице летать по синусу. В чем вопрос-то? Если же вам нужен не синус, а что-то еще, тогда формализуйте то, что вы хотите получить

Comment: @DmitriySimushev Кривую которая менялась бы не равномерно

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich, вы ведь понимаете, что множество "_Кривых, которые менялись бы не равномерно_" является неограниченным? Даже если выделить подмножество кривых что "_похожи на синусоиды_" оно все равно будет неограниченным

Comment: @DmitriySimushev Просто если добавлять рандом на каких то промежутках полёта получаются рывки, подошла бы любая кривая не такая идеальная как синус. Помню точно такие были когда математику учил =)

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich, такая функция пойдёт? `exp(-0.005x)*sin(0.04x)`

Comment: @LEQADA по прямой летит поему то, пока не понял почему

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich, это график затухающих колебаний. Прямой быть не может.

Comment: @LEQADA Добавил множитель 1000 получается более менее интересно. Добавьте как ответ, желательно с графиком, если других предложений не будет отмечу как лучший. Местами взлетает очень резко.

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich, с такой функцией ваша птица в какой-то момент начнёт очень ровно летать. Вы точно так хотели?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать сумму синусоидальных функций с различной длинной волны и амплитудой. В качестве примера, я построил график зависимости:

```
y(x) = 130 + 12 * sin(x / 4) + 47 * sin(x / 3) + 52 * sin(x / 2) + 3 * sin(x * 3)
```

и получил вот такую кривую:

[image: График зависимости y(x)]

А вот пример зависимости, которая (наверное) больше подходит к вашей задаче:

```
y(x) = 130 + 12 * sin(x / 12.5) + 27 * sin(x / 9.5) + 32 * sin(x / 6.25) + 3 * sin(x)
```

[image: Зависимость y(x) про птичку]

Вообще, множество кривых, описываемых суммой синусоидальных функций является неограниченным. Варьируя коэффициенты и количество слагаемых вы сможете построить ту самую функцию, которая вам нужна.

Answer (score 6):

Не обязательно использовать тригонометрию. Плавную кривую можно получать, если рисующий «карандаш» следует хвостом за точкой-целью – [кривая погони](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8). В каждый кадр карандаш *K* получает изменение координат как долю вектора из своего положения до точки-цели *G*, с коэффициентом замедления/плавности *k* < 1:

```
Kx += (Gx - Kx) / k;
Ky += (Gy - Ky) / k;
```

[Попробовать](https://apps.sergeisokolov.com/calligraphy/), как это работает – там за мышкой следуют 3 точки, одна за другой – последняя рисует. Экспериментировал в поиске эстетически приятных кривых.

Такой метод, по-моему, даже больше подойдёт для вашей задачи – можно обходить горы и спускаться в долины – задавать особенности рельефа малым кол-вом контрольных точек (и случайно отклонять каждую в небольших диапазонах), где должна побывать «цель» по ходу анимации.

Точку-цель перемещать по одному разу для каждого «горба» кривой. Т.е. она должна чередовать верхнюю/нижнюю половину, и чуть случайно отклоняться от строгой «пилы» для разнообразия. В том моём примере сначала отогнать карандаш влево на середину, и затем скачками перемещать «цель». У меня получилось так:

[image: плавная кривая]

Comment: У тригонометрических функций есть одна очень приятная особенность "из коробки" -- периодичность. А вот для случаев, когда периодичность мешает (неравномерный ландшафт), ваш вариант действительно хорош.

Comment: Как я увидел на сайте ТС, птица пытается облететь гору. Можно (привет Фурье), но нетривиально подобрать коэффициенты тригонометрических ф-ий, чтобы получилась желаемая форма.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы предложил после каждого перехода Y через ноль менять амплитуду случайно, то есть вместо 100 ставить 90 или 110.

Comment: Тяжело понять где ноль

Comment: birds.y = 4 * Math.sin(birds.x)+200;
Например тут нужно проверить когда birds.y == 0 или близко к нулю. 
Написать как это сделать ?

Comment: y всё время положительный, а график может уходить далеко в + и минимально это 0 Максимум по сути это размер экрана, но она как бы может уходить за горизонт